# Multiprocessing output to file

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pid

Is there a way to redirect the stream to file when creating an instance of class Process or during execution `Process(target=..., args=(...)).start()`

I asked about the typical pythonic way

```python
Process(target=start_test, args=(timestamp,current_test_suite,user_ip)).start()
```

If there is no pythonic way to do that maybe linux can redirect PID output to file?

Comment: Great This is exactly what I need. I didn't notice this post. Thanks man :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to redirect Process output to file we have to assign `sys.stdout` to `open(filename,'w')` or `open(filename,'a')` if we want to appending our log file.